# SQL Error 1062 Duplicate Entry

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having an `MYSQL` error when someone registers, not everyone though, only for some users. Why is that?

Error:

> SQL ERROR: 1062 Duplicate entry 'Fedot_Pulemiot' for key 'username'

Comment: The main reason why the error has been generated is because there is already an existing value  for that column. Can you please share your tables definition like columns and data types?

Comment: Assuming you want the `user_name` to be unique, you should do a check if the name isn't already taken. If it's taken you don't execute the `INSERT` query but you return a meaningful error to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid duplicate entry we can add unique constrain to the column, sql as follows

```
ALTER TABLE `user` ADD UNIQUE(`user_name`);
```

But in your case i think already unique is set so drop the unique value as follows

```
ALTER TABLE tb_name DROP INDEX user_name;
```